# how fill a object in actionContext.Response.Content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, object, httpresponse

first sorry for my bad english guys :)
i want to  put data in actionContext.Response.Content . how to set an object in response.content . this is my code

```
var c = actionContext.Request.RequestUri.ToString();
var d = ObjCache.Get(c);
if (d != null)
{
    actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse();
    actionContext.Response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotModified;
    actionContext.Response.Content = new StringContent(d.ToString());
    var ResultData= actionContext.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;     
}
```

the problem is actionContext.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result returns type of the object in it as a string .but i want the object itself.
thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of object you want? You may want to try the other extention method - Response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ObjectType>().Result.

Comment: thnx . worked for me